# Does __all__ have to be a list?

Tags: python, python-import

I know [what `__all__` is used for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44834/562769), but I wonder why everybody is using a list for it. Is there a drawback of using a tuple? Would one want `__all__` to be mutable?